# jquery highlight applies a ton, how to avoid it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I'm doing a website  for reserving seats on a train.
The form needs a calculator for the price to show the client a total amount 
while he/she is selecting service, quantity of passengers, etc.

To make more obvious the change in the total cost I used the jq highlight effect on the div, just to get more attention.

The problem is that I had it highlight when a slider slides, so if I pass from 0 to 56 (max seats on the train wagon) the highlight occurs 56 times.

Hopefully you could help out, or suggest a better idea.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    /**/
    function calculateTotal(){
        //var unitPrice = 2, paperTypes = 2, printedSides = 2;
        var precio_base  = $('#categoria option:selected').val();
        var cant_adultos = $("#adultos").val();

        var cant_ninos = $("#ninos").val();
        var sum = parseInt(cant_adultos) + parseInt(cant_ninos);
        var precio_productos = $("input[name^='servicio']").parseNumber();

        var totalCost = parseInt(precio_base)*parseInt(sum);

        $('#total-box').html("$"+totalCost);
        $('#total-box').effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
    }

    $('#categoria,#adultos,#ninos').change(calculateTotal).highlight();

});
```

The page is at http://www.micontrol.cl/~mvargas/wordpress/wp-transatacama/reservas-rapidas/form-reservas.php.

Comment: I guess that jQuery UI Effect doesn't handle asynchronous effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop triggering the change event on every slide step.
Just trigger that on stop event. ex: http://jsbin.com/atolax/2

Comment: WOW great, thanks :D i didn't know that, but now I do thanks to you... PD: that wasn't the exact behaviour i was looking for but it will do

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the slider widget from jQuery UI (jQuery UI appears to be included on the page you linked to), you could bind to the [`stop`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-stop) event instead of `change`. Something like this:

```
$("#yourSlider").bind("slidestop", calculateTotal).highlight();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i will create a new code that uses that, but I don't know how to use bind()... thanx now i have a new thing to learn :D (y)

Comment: No problem :) Just have a look at the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/bind/ You've used `change` in your question, that's just shorthand for `.bind("change", function() { ... });`